# ImageMagick scale and crop keeping aspect ratio

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am trying without success to scale an image to 250 px width keeping aspect ratio using ImageMagick and then crop it from top corner (x,y) with size 160 px width and 160 px height.

I have tried this with PHP, but it s not working:

```
exec($homePath.'/ImageMagick/bin/mogrify -resize 250x -crop 160x160'+'.$x.'+'.$y
     .' test.jpg');
```

I have even tried 2 instructions like below:

```
//Resize is not working
exec($homePath.'/ImageMagick/bin/mogrify -resize 250x test.jpg');

//Crop is working
exec($homePath.'/ImageMagick/bin/mogrify -crop 160x160'.'+'.$x.'+'.$y.' test.jpg');
```

I m using ImageMagick 7.0.7-4

Comment: What do you mean not working? Can you change `mogrify` to `convert` and check results?

Comment: In Imagemagick 7, convert is magick and mogrify is magick mogrify. I would recommend you use magick in place of mogrify, if you are just processing one image at a time. Also after a crop, you need to add +repage, if you are saving to a file format such as PNG or TIF that save the virtual canvas. JPG is fine without it. Try `exec($homePath.'/ImageMagick/bin/magick mogrify -resize 250x -crop 160x160'+'.$x.'+'.$y.'  test.jpg');`

Comment: Also it seems your quotes may not be correct. I am not an expert on PHP exec, but try exec("$homePath.'/ImageMagick/bin/magick mogrify -resize 250x -crop 160x160+'.$x.'+'.$y.' test.jpg'");

Comment: It's still not resizing the image, even  with **magick mogrify** or with **magick convert**. When i only test the crop with  `exec($homePath.'/ImageMagick/bin/mogrify -crop 160x160'.'+'.$x.'+'.$y.' test.jpg');` the image is cropped. I don t understand why the resizing is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally with the Help of @fmw42, who focus my attention on the term **magick** before **mogrify** in **ImageMagick 7**:

```
 exec($homePath.'/ImageMagick/bin/magick mogrify -scale 250x 
      -crop 160x160+'.$x.'+'.$y.' test.jpg');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the libpng delegate library installed? You can check with `magick -version` and see if it lists png. There is no reason that -resize should not work if -scale does. It depends upon the result you want. -scale will be faster but gives a more blurred result.

Comment: @fmw42 I finally installed another ImageMagick package and everything just works fine. Thanks for your help.